# I'm not able to view a website through a frame in firefox, but I can in Chrome. How do I modify the browser settings to not block it?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, browser

I am trying to display another website I've built through an iframe. I can view the site if I use Chrome, but when I try and view it in Firefox I just get a blank frame. I found the article about x-frames and have verified that I don't have them turned on in the webpage or IIS, and since I can view in Chrome that seems to confirm this. Is there a setting in Firefox that is preventing me from viewing the frame content? How do I allow it to be viewed?

I'm trying to load the frame in a visualforce page ie: apex:iframe src="my website"

It loads just fine in chrome, but I get a blank frame when I load it in firefox.

I found the article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003366&language=en_US which suggests the issue the browser, but I can't find a setting in the browser and a web search has yielded no help.

Using height and width tags make no difference.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Are you sure you're looking at the header X-Frame-Options? Can you post the headers?

Comment: The only HTTP Response Header shown in IIS is X-Powered-By and I am able to view the frame content when I load salesforce in Chrome. The article leads me to believe the problem is something with firefox and showing frames within salesforce.

Comment: Additional Info:

I just tried to load it in IE and a popup message was displayed saying only secure content was displayed. I clicked on the link to show all content and my frame content was displayed.

Answer (score 3):

From my comment leaving additional information I was able to expand my internet search and found that since firefox version 23 it starts to block mixed content by default. In order to display non secure frame content in a secured website (like salesforce) you have to click on the shield icon located next to the lock icon in the address bar. This brings up a warning about the mixed content. Just click on the drop down and tell it to display the content.

Comment: Does the other site provide an HTTPS version? Mixed content is a Bad Thing.